Strange behaviour in size of greek letters in combination with vmatrix
I am experimenting this thing when I use the cases environment in combination with \frac.
When, for example $\alpha$ is put near a vmatrix at numerator of a fraction and inside cases environment, then $\alpha$ is smaller than its homologous inside the array.
Here is my minimal working example
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
        
\[\begin{gathered}
    \begin{cases}
    \frac{\begin{vmatrix}
        \alpha&\alpha\\ \alpha&\alpha
\end{vmatrix}}{\begin{vmatrix}
1&2\\3&4
\end{vmatrix}}=\frac{\alpha\begin{vmatrix}
1&1\\1&1
\end{vmatrix}}{\begin{vmatrix}
1&2\\3&4
\end{vmatrix}}
\end{cases}
\qquad\begin{cases}
\frac{\begin{vmatrix}
        1+\alpha&2\\3+\alpha&4
\end{vmatrix}}{\begin{vmatrix}
        1&2\\3&4
\end{vmatrix}}=\frac{\begin{vmatrix}
        1&2\\3&4
    \end{vmatrix}+\alpha\begin{vmatrix}
        1&2\\1&4
\end{vmatrix}}{\begin{vmatrix}
        1&2\\3&4
\end{vmatrix}}
\end{cases}\\ \begin{cases}
\begin{vmatrix}
    1&2\\3&4\\
\end{vmatrix}+\alpha\begin{vmatrix}
1&2\\1&4
\end{vmatrix}
\end{cases} \frac{\begin{vmatrix}
    1&2\\3&4
\end{vmatrix}+\alpha\begin{vmatrix}
    1&2\\1&4
    \end{vmatrix}}{\begin{vmatrix}
    1&2\\3&4
    \end{vmatrix}}
\end{gathered}
\]
\end{document}

And here is an image where you can see that some greek letters are smaller than others.


vmatrix is not involved at all, the example can be simplified to

\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
        
\[
\alpha +    \begin{cases}
\alpha + \frac{\alpha}{\alpha}
\end{cases}
\qquad
\]

$\alpha + \frac{\alpha}{\alpha}$
\end{document}

in textstyle fractions use scriptstyle characters in the numerator and denominator
if you do not want that. use \dfrac

\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
        
\[
\alpha +    \begin{cases}
\alpha + \dfrac{\alpha}{\alpha}
\end{cases}
\qquad
\]

$\alpha + \dfrac{\alpha}{\alpha}$
\end{document}


@ David  I see. The point is that I use alphas inside and outside a vmatrix (or array in general) and different sizes are ugly. I thought (wrongly) that inside a displaymath all fractions were displaystyle.

the fields inside cases are textstyle, just as if you nest fractions with \frac the outer one uses \textstyle numerator (same size characters) but the a nested \frac is in textstyle so will use smaller scriptstyle characters. You would see the same with a not just Greek. @Antonio

@Antonio so really here the error is misusing cases wen you are not haveing any function being given by case that is what is forcing the cramped style (but using \dfrac is probably the simplest fix

@ David I use cases as delimiter for a system of linear equations and vmatrices follow from Cramer rule. Maybe I should kick the habit for something else. Any tips?
